# AJAX Post - Performed in JSP, need to return java based variables in the AJAX POST Success function

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using ajax post within a JSP, to send json data to a servlet java class. Within the servlet controller class I used getparameter to get the data being sent from the calling JSP.

This all works fine, to this point. I then initate processing of the data in from this servlet class, and I need to formulate a data response to send back to the calling JSP.

Is there a way that I can hold the data in variables within the servelt class, and as part of the success function (within my AJAX post) access this data?

My AJAX Post code:

```
    $.ajax({ 
        type:        "POST", 
        url:           url, 
        dataType:  "text",  // [text, xml, json, script, text, html]
        data:       {postData : myData, sendURL : postUrl}, 
        success:    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
            alert('Success post to URL entered \n\n The data returned the following: ' + data);
        }, 
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ 
            alert('Error xhr : ' + xhr.status); 
            alert('Error thrown error: ' + thrownError); 
        }
        //complete: alert('complete')                   
    });
```

My Servlet Controller code:

```
    @RequestMapping("/postData")
    public String postData(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws Throwable{

        String postData = request.getParameter("postData");
        String sendURL= request.getParameter("sendURL");

        System.out.println(this.getClass() + " : postData   : " + postData);
        System.out.println(this.getClass() + " : gatewayURL : " + gatewayURL);

        /* Process data and formulate a response.... */

        String responseText = processedResponseText; // This processedResponseText was populated in the internal processing
        String responseCode = processedResponseCode; // This processedResponseCode was populated in the internal processing

        return "callingJSP";
    }
```

As part of my AJAX Post - Success function, how can I get these two variables (responseText and responseCode) back to the calling JSP?

Many thanks

Comment: Anything you want to access using JavaScript has to be part of the response sent to the browser. How you format that is up to you, though JSON seems like the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the structure of the data that's coming in (you should!), create an object that the post data can be serialized to (I'm assuming myData is json?... if not, it should be!) by the servlet. The spring framework provides the @RequestBody annotation to deserialize the incoming json to your object. When the servlet needs to respond, do what @Jigar recommended: wrap your response in an object. The spring framework provides the @ResponseBody annotation to serialize your response to json. It could look something like this:

Your js:

```
var myData = { postId: 1, comment: "this is great!" };
 $.ajax({ 
        type:        "POST", 
        url:           url, 
        dataType:  "text",  // [text, xml, json, script, text, html]
        data:       {postData : myData, sendURL : postUrl}, 
        success:    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var jsonRepsonse = JSON.parse(data);
            alert('Success post to URL entered \n\n The data returned the following: ' + jsonRepsonse.responseText + ", " + jsonRepsonse.responseCode);
        }, 
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ 
            alert('Error xhr : ' + xhr.status); 
            alert('Error thrown error: ' + thrownError); 
        }
        //complete: alert('complete')                   
    });
```

Your Java object:

```
class Comment {
  private long postId;
  private String comment;
  // getters & setters
}
```

Your wrapped response object:

```
class AjaxResponse{
 private String responseText;
 private String responseCode;
 //other stuff
}
```

The handler function in your controller:

```
 @RequestMapping("/postData")
 public @ResponseBody postData(Model model, 
             @RequestBody Comment comment,
             HttpServletRequest request) throws Throwable{

    String sendURL= request.getParameter("sendURL");

    System.out.println(this.getClass() + " : comment : " + comment.toString());

    /* Process data and formulate a response.... */

    AjaxResponse ajaxResponse = new AjaxResponse(processedResponseText, processedResponseCode);

    return ajaxResponse;
 }
```

Ideally your AjaxResponse contains another object instead of text that provides more information about the response. For example, you may want to change your AjaxResponse object as follows:

```
class CommentResponse extends Comment {
   private long commentId;
   private Timestamp entryDateTime;
   // etc
}

class AjaxResponse{
 private CommentResponse commentResponse;
 private String responseCode;
 //other stuff
}
```

Doing this helps you immensely when receiving the response on the front end, but it depends on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Also..

Success will return the response

```
success:    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
       alert('Success post to URL entered \n\n The data returned the following: ' + data);
    },
```

No need of XHR and textStatus in the success function should be like :

```
success:    function(response) { 
       alert('Success post to URL entered \n\n The data returned the following: ' + response.responseText);
    },
```